# How to show status in PHP, not the number, but the actual text?

Tags: php, status

I want to fetch the data from database from user database.
In my database, the status is in number like 1 and 0.
I want to show the status of a user in the form of "active" or "not active" when 1, so it's "active" and respectively.

```
<tr>
  <td>Status:</td>
  <td><?= $user_data['status'] ?></td>
  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><?= $user_data['status'] == 1 ? 'active' : 'not active' ?></td>
```